# Can't break "while" cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

SO, Hello! I am coding my first programm and i need help with the next problem:
The folowing code is getting a str then asking about if it shall get another string. If the answer is yes it should ask for the next string, but if the answer is no it should break the cycle "while". Well in fact what is happening cycle is breaking only after working so much times as much items u enterd.
Here's a [link](https://repl.it/M4Ta/0) for webinterpriter.
Sorry for my english.

```
inplist = []
def products_inp():
    inp = ""
    inp = input("lets see watcha got...\n")
    inplist.append(inp)
    print(inplist)
    while True:
        selector = ""
        selector = input("smth else? (Y/N)\n")
        if selector.lower() == 'y':
            products_inp()
        elif selector.lower() == 'n':
            print("Got'em! loading...")
            break
        else:
            print("aint got it...")
products_inp()
```

Comment: The issue is that you're recursively calling your function, which means that you have nested while loops that each have to be broken for each invocation of your function.  You'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: `return products_inp()` would do.

Answer (score 1):

Viable:

```
def myfunc():
  while True:
    # do something static here.
    if condition:
      break
```

Not viable:

```
def myfunc():
  while True:
    myfunc()
    break
```

With the former setup, as long as you don't call `myfunc()`, breaking breaks the only while loop.  With the latter setup (yours), each time you call `myfunc()` from within your function, you create a nested `while True` loop.  You have to break each one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are recursively calling the function, you are nesting your `while` loop, meaning that it needs to be broken out of each time you call the function. It would be better to exclude the whole loop from the function to result in

```
inplist = []
def products_inp():
    inp = ""
    inp = input("lets see watcha got...\n")
    inplist.append(inp)
    print(inplist)

while True:
    selector = ""
    selector = input("smth else? (Y/N)\n")
    if selector.lower() == 'y':
        products_inp()
    elif selector.lower() == 'n':
        print("Got'em! loading...")
        break
    else:
        print("aint got it...")
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, another approach to tackle a problem like this is to not use a while loop that you have to break. Sometimes there is no way around this but in your case you could easily rearrange your code into a function that takes user input, and then a while loop with a boolean expression, such that if the user wants to input more it remains true and if they enter n it becomes false terminating the loop. This also makes it easier to read.